# Is it preferable to have high activity fields in Cassandra exist in their own table?

Tags: cassandra, nosql

Let's say I'm implementing a forum system (let's think something like Reddit or even SO) that's backed by Cassandra.

A post has multiple fields, like content, timestamp, etc, plus a `rating` (upvotes plus downvotes). Posts are backed by a POSTS table. Let's assume for the sake of the argument that I don't care to know which specific users did upvote or downvote, I just care about a post's total rating.

I'm wondering if there's any advantage in storing the ratings in a RATINGS (post_id, rating) table instead of just having it as a field in POSTS, given that there are going to be lots of upvotes / downvotes happening all the time.

Given Cassandra's architecture, what would be the ins and outs of choosing one approach over the other?

Answer (score 0):

Putting rating in another table will not make sense as it appears you will be using the same partition key for both tables (POSTS and RATINGS). You can always get ratings from POSTS table. I don't see any benefit in creating RATINGS table.